# Getting error about Lucene version 3.0.3.0 while upgrading Sitecore version to 7.0

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6, sitecore7

Earlier we were using Lucene version 2.3.1.3(Sitecore version 6.5) everything working fine but now we have upgraded to sitecore version 7.0(Initial release) and now we are using  Lucene version 3.0.3.0 dll in project.
But now we are not able to compile project because of errors in code file.
Does that means Lucene version 3.0.3.0 dll doesn't support code written in Lucene version 2.3.1.3(Sitecore version 6.5)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Sitecore 6.x to 7.0 needs some adjustments in code to get everything work again.

Which error do you get? I also had a specific error regarding lucene dll when compiling after the upgrade but this error was only caused by a wrong assembly redirect in the web.config.

In fact, the search API changed completely and if you made an upgrade to 7.0 it is recommended to update your search logic to the possibilities are now available in 7.0 like LINQ support and so on. Search is much more comfortable now in sitecore 7 and it is really worth taking a closer look at the changes. They took a lot of the advanced database crawler module like dynamic fields (they are now called computed fields) and much more and added it to the sitecore 7 standard search api.

Comment: Actually in my application RangeQuery and QueryFilter classes are used in LucenceHelper.cs class and due to this I'm not able to build website.
I think Lucence 3.0.3.0 dll doesn't support these classes and I have to analyze existing code and need to change according to Lucence 3.0.3.0 dll version but how do I know what code should I replace.

Apart from that I put following web.config changes for Lucence:
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Lucene.Net" publicKeyToken="85089178b9ac3181" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.9.4.0" newVersion="3.0.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

Comment: In the new sitecore search api, range querys are made using LINQ. You do not need RangeQuery any more. Linq can be used for int, date, string, float etc. You can take a look at implementation examples like this http://www.fusionworkshop.co.uk/news-and-insight/tech-lab/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide to get a feeling what's possible in sitecore 7 search.